# Json output invalid format

Tags: php, json, api

Problem with json output data shows Invalid

Here is what i want to do, 
Get api response from other server in json format, decode to array and extract the required data and save the extracted data to newArray and then encode the newArray back to json and print to screen
But the problem i face is the printed json shows invalid json format 
When i look at the rawdata  i notice there is no **[** at the begin and no **]** at the end 
Also there is no **, coma** for next data block.

Here is my code

```
$array = json_decode($eng_sub, 1 );

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++  ){
    $resp_array['Movie Name'] = $array[$i]['MovieName'];
    $resp_array['Movie Year'] = $array[$i]['MovieYear'];
    $resp_array['Language'] = $array[$i]['LanguageName'];
    $resp_array['Link'] = $array[$i]['ZipDownloadLink'];
    $json = json_encode($resp_array);
    print_r ($json);
    }
```

And here is the response from my code after re-encoded to json

```
{"Movie Name":"Avatar","Movie Year":"2009","Language":"Urdu","Link":"https:\/\/dl.opensubtitles.org\/en\/download\/src-api\/vrf-f52f0bb6\/subad\/7006619"}{"Movie Name":"TEKNO3D.com Avatar 2009 4K VISIONPLUSHDR-1000 4:2:0 Edition S01","Movie Year":"2009","Language":"Urdu","Link":"https:\/\/dl.opensubtitles.org\/en\/download\/src-api\/vrf-f5410bb6\/subad\/7600673"}
```

Im doing this in XAMPP PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prepare your array and then do a **single** json_encode on it:

```
$array = json_decode($eng_sub, 1 );

echo json_encode(array_map(function($row) {
  return [
    'Movie Name' => $row['MovieName'],
    'Movie Year' => $row['MovieYear'],
    'Language' => $row['LanguageName'],
    'Link' => $row['ZipDownloadLink'],
  ];
}, $array));
```

Comment: Awesome  solved. i was going crazy to fix it